# Get the check box value after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Here is my form & my current URL is .../pg/members/all

```
<form id="simplesearch" name="simplesearch" action="<?php echo $vars['url'];?>pg/members/searchuser" method="post">
<table class="people_search" style="border:none;">

       <div id="toggle_profile_type">
       <input type="hidden" value="0" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type]">
       <p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39242" class="messageCheckbox"><span>Job Seeker</span></p>
       <p class="skills_odd1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39243" class="messageCheckbox"><span>Employer</span></p>
       <p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39449" class="messageCheckbox"><span>college</span></p>
       </div>

</table>
</form>
```

In script i have written

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(":checkbox").click(function(){
    simplesearchsubmitform();
  }); 
});

function simplesearchsubmitform()
{
  if(document.simplesearchonsubmit && !document.simplesearch.onsubmit()) {
    return;
  }
  document.simplesearch.submit();
}
```

I am submitting the form then the URL changes ..../pg/members/searchuser. Now i need to get the selected `checkbox` values. So that i can append that value to in a div & the checkbox will remain selected.

Any idea guys how do it ? I searched a lot but i didn't found the solution. plz help me guys..

Comment: inside click function you can get it by `$(this).val()` then pass it to the `simplesearchsubmitform` as an argument

Comment: Hey i am new to it. So can you explain more then it will be helpful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At "pg/members/searchuser"

**Update 2.0**
You use this code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria']))
{  

   foreach($_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria'] as $val)
   {
        foreach($val as $checkbox_data)
        {
            echo $checkbox_data."<br/>";
        }
   }
 } else 
 {
     echo "No checkbox checked";
 }
?>
```

How to select the checkboxes:
There are 2 methods, with JS or with PHP.
The jQuery snippet:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{


<?php

if(isset($_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria']))
{  

   foreach($_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria'] as $val)
   {
        foreach($val as $checkbox_data)
        {

            ?>
            $('input:checkbox[value="<?php echo $checkbox_data;?>"]').attr('checked','checked');
            <?php
        }
   }
 } else 
 {
     echo "No checkbox checked";
 }
?>
})
</script>
```

What it does? It will select those checkboxes,which values we got from $_POST.

Comment: instead of the name can we use class or id in `$_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type]']`

Comment: yes now its passing the value but how can i make the check box selected & van i use this the value to show inside a div

Comment: I added a new section to my answer.

Comment: Its working but while loading the page its showing the echo the code like this `// if(isset($_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria'])) // { //  //  foreach($_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria'] as $val) //  { //  foreach($val as $checkbox_data) //  { //  echo $checkbox_data."
"; //  } //  } //  } else //  { //  echo "No checkbox checked"; //  }`

Comment: You should put those things inside <?php ?> wrapper.

Comment: Can i append this value to any div right by using jquery.

Comment: Yes you can. You have the data now,you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: I have written like this  `$("font.job_query_strings").append(<?php echo $checkbox_data;?>).val();
              $("font.job_query_strings").show();` but the value is coming like ".$checkbox_data."   39243. How to do it correct

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the values into an array like this:

```
var values = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]']:checked"), function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending that form with POST to a new URL.
So you need to catch all values with PHP and not with JavaScript.
At ".../pg/members/searchuser" you just ask for all $_POST and then select your checkboxes with these values.

Comment: Take the solution from Beardminator. That is what I meant and the easiest way to solve your problem. No need for extra JavaScript. Just simple PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this sample, it will display the checked value based on the post

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria'])){
        $data = $_POST['meta_data_array_search_criteria'];

        if (is_array($data['custom_profile_type'])){
            //check and display checked value
            if (in_array('39242', $data['custom_profile_type']))
                echo '<p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39242" class="messageCheckbox" checked><span>Job Seeker</span></p>';
            else
                echo '<p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39242" class="messageCheckbox"><span>Job Seeker</span></p>';

            if (in_array('39243', $data['custom_profile_type']))
                    echo '<p class="skills_odd1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39243" class="messageCheckbox" checked><span>Employer</span></p>';
                else
                    echo '<p class="skills_odd1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39243" class="messageCheckbox"><span>Employer</span></p>';

            if (in_array('39449', $data['custom_profile_type']))
                    echo '<p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39449" class="messageCheckbox" checked><span>college</span></p>';
                else
                    echo '<p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39449" class="messageCheckbox"><span>college</span></p>';

        }
        else{
            //display all unchecked
            echo '<p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39242" class="messageCheckbox"><span>Job Seeker</span></p>';
            echo '<p class="skills_odd1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39243" class="messageCheckbox"><span>Employer</span></p>';
            echo '<p class="skills_even1"><input type="checkbox" name="meta_data_array_search_criteria[custom_profile_type][]" value="39449" class="messageCheckbox"><span>college</span></p>';
        }

    }   
?>
```

Comment: Sorry its a good idea but its not possible, for just sample i posted the question but the check box are coming from different file. I called the file in a variable. That variable is inside a form & i am submitting that form. So its a lengthy one.. thnx

Comment: You mean the value, i.e, 39242, is coming from a file? If this is the case, I think you just need to make a inner loop to check the in_array and print out the checkbox.